# Date format conversion issue PHP

Tags: php, date

See the below code returns the output as **"Jun"**.

```
$date_removed =strtotime('2017-06-07 06:06:44'); 
$datev = date('d-m-Y', $date_removed);
$nameOfMonth = date('M', strtotime($datev));
echo $nameOfMonth;
```

But the below code returns **"Dec"** as output.

```
$date_removed =strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00'); 
$datev = date('d-m-Y', $date_removed);
$nameOfMonth = date('M', strtotime($datev));
echo $nameOfMonth;
```

Here the month value is null. So the return value should be null. Please let me know the issue in my code?

Comment: Could be because first date in unix time is 1970 01 01. So if you are in a different timezone you may get 1969 12 31 thus december.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: Below code needs to show `Jan`, correct?

Comment: What is there to solve? What is the problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: 2017-06-07 06:06:44 this returns "Jun", hope 06 is the month name. So 0000-00-00 00:00:00 this should return null. Not "Jan"

Comment: Why do you think it shold do that? Just add a if ("0000-00-00...")

Comment: your code is working correct - I tested and below code return `Jan`. so issue is not in your code but somewhere else.

Comment: @dekts it depends on timezone

Comment: @Nuju check my answer below

Comment: @nuju what if you check "0000-00-00 00:00:00" before process

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` will return false if the date is invalid so you can check that using the return type:

```
<?php
$date_removed =strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00'); 
if($date_removed>0)
{
    $datev = date('d-m-Y', $date_removed);
    $nameOfMonth = date('M', strtotime($datev));
    echo $nameOfMonth;    
}
else
    echo "invalid date"; //or whatever you want
```

Comment: It returns "Dec" for me

Comment: Returns Jan for me. But this will do it: https://3v4l.org/ANFjS `$date_removed` is a negative number before UNIX (1970)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to do it like this:

```
try { 
    $dt = new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00'); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    var_dump($e); 
}
```

Comment: See [How do you explain the result for a new \DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10450644): *This code does not throw an Exception, even if it should*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Canada/Central");
$date_removed = mktime(00, 00, 0000);

if($date_removed)
{
    $datev = date('Y/m/d',$date_removed);
    $nameOfMonth = date('M', strtotime($datev));
    echo $nameOfMonth;    
}
else
    echo "invalid date"; //or whatever you want
?>
```